# How to safely avoid earth cable?

Tags: power, mains, safety

I'm a software developer (in the uk) and I've been sent some hardware to use as part of my testing, but the way the non-uk manufacturer is telling me to wire it up sounds very sketchy to me.

Its a device used to measure power usage where its expected to take in a live/neutral, measure power and then continue. They suggest taking something like a desk lamp, cut the wire and use its live/neutral in/out of the device and continue as normal. But uk devices all use an earth cable which they say I should just ignore and leave disconnected.

Is this safe or is there a better option here? I'm wondering if it'd be better to reconnect the earth directly and bypass the measuring tool but also not sure about this.

Note: I'm not expecting to run this light/circuit constantly but more likely up to an hour maximum

[image]

Comment: For your own safety, leave the Earth wire connected (or reconnect it after you cut the cable to reroute the live & neutral). And although I'm sure it's obvious, do this when the plug it *not* plugged in!

Comment: @brhans - Many thanks! Im going no way near a plug socket till I'm comfortable its safe!

Comment: Since you are a SW dev, use an isolated debugger, or an isolated USB connection in addition to the answers below.

Comment: "But uk devices all use an earth cable" - not true, many devices just have a live/neutral connection and they're interchangeable. The laptop supply I'm using right now, for instance. IF there is an earth wire it MUST stay connected.

Comment: cut an extension cord in half and install the device in the middle

Comment: *they say I should just ignore and leave disconnected.* Absolutely don't listen to that advice. The PE conductor is for electrical safety. The power meter is supposed to work either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reconnection of the earth is "a very good idea".
If the device being measured has no faults then the earth connection does nothing.  If a phase to ground connection occurs the earth wire is part of the fuse blowing / contactor tripping system.

In the case of a portable (non fixed) light the earth often is not connected to anything significant. If there is bare metal it should be earthed.

Many lighting fittings use only two wires and are often "safe enough".
If an earth wire is provided for a device with no exposed metal it may add to overall safety, but may make minimal difference in practice.

Use of an earth leak circuit breaker / ground fault interrupter is a good idea in any situation where safety is of concern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the safest option is to connect the earth ground directly to the earth ground of the outlet without going through the electronic device. Often cheap desk lamps do not have an earth ground, so your engineers probably did not consider this.

I would consider getting an isolation transformer with a fuse if I was in your case. This creates a circuit that is independent of the utility AC circuit, which lowers the chance of damage from your device contacting ground.

Another thing to ask your engineers is is your microcontroller or whatever you're developing software for isolated from AC? Generally yes, but many (cheaper) circuits create a logic power source directly from the AC line without isolation, which is dangerous for you as a developer using debugging tools.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure your desk lamp uses earth at all? If the lamp has only two wires, live and neutral, going to the plug, then the lamp does not have or use the earth. The plug may also have a plastic earth prong just to open the shutters for live and neutral, so not even the plug has use for earth. But of course, if you have an earthed device, you must keep it earthed.

Perhaps embed the device into a plastic box with mains plug and mains socket, with the earth passing directly from plug to socket and the other wires going through the device, so you don't have to play with bare wires or earthing.